# how do I take a numbers from text fields and when I click a button I will see the average on a label?

Tags: ios, objective-c, textfield, average

i really need help.

i need to take 5 or 10 (i don't know now) text fields and when i click a button i will see the average of the numbers i typed (I will change the keyboard to numbers only + ".").

for example if i have 5 text fields and i type on the first 60, on the second 70 and the third 80 i want to see the average of the numbers but if i haven't typed on the forth and fifth text fields i don't want them to include in the calculation.

I hope some one can help me
thanks :)

Comment: You need to show us that you have some basic understand of iOS programming.  Have you set up your 5 text fields?  Tell us how you did that.  Have you set up your button?  Have you connected it to an action?  If you don't understand those questions, or you don't know how to answer them, you need to work through some basic iOS programming tutorials.

Comment: I do have understand iOS programming but I an learning now I now a lot but I just don't now how to do it

Comment: i made all the IBOutlets and the action

Comment: https://copy.com/AFOx7cqMCsit

Comment: @נבושלו Yeah, that's not a suspicious looking link at all...

Comment: Its just a screenshot...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's hard to understand what exactly you're asking. You're trying to get the entered in values in `UITextField`'s, then average them, correct? If so, that will look something like this:
Get each value entered in the text fields like this :

```
`NSString *firstTextFieldText = yourTextFieldsName.text;`
```

Convert to int:

```
`int firstTextFieldIntValue = [firstTextFieldText intValue];`
```

Do that with all four text fields. Then, average them all up:

```
int total = (firstTextFieldIntValue + secondTextFieldIntValue + thirdTextFieldIntValue + fourthTextFieldIntValue) / 4;
```

That should work. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: It's bad form to delete you previous answer and then repost a new, exact answer just because you don't agree with a down vote. And no, I didn't down vote your other answer.

Comment: @נבושלו No problem. Also, please "accept" the answer if it was correct.

Comment: @rmaddy I didn't delete it because of a down vote, but thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I sorry I am new in this web site and I done really now how it works.
sorry

Comment: Then why did you delete your previous answer and post another with virtually identical text?

Comment: @נבושלו No problem, welcome to Stack. And @ rmaddy, I'm writing this on my phone and my previous answer went on the fritz. What's the big deal?

Comment: is it bad ? by mistakenly...

Comment: @John For future reference, just edit your answer to make any change instead of deleting and reposting.

Comment: @rmaddy Sure thing, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: if i don't type a number on one of the text fields how to i make to divide only the text fields that has a number ?

Comment: @נבושלו Throw a conditional in there to check and see if the text field is blank, like `if (! [textFieldName isEqualToString@"")`. That's basically saying "if the text field is not blank, do x.

Comment: what if i have 100 text fields is there an easier way to make it ?

Answer (score -1):

you can initialize a variable to count, on each text field if a textfield has text or numbers do +1 if its empty add 0 and you use that counter variable to divide the sum of the numbers over the initilized variable :)

also in the utilities while looking in you UIViewController that you have the textfileds , select them and in the utilities look for the option of number keyboard i dont remeber exactly where it was but its in the utilities on the right side and i think you have to scroll down a little bit for it.